# Node listings on taxonomy term page

Tags: taxonomy-terms, theming

How to disable/remove node listings on taxonomy term page in Drupal 8?

Comment: You can alter the view that creates this page to your specific needs. If you don't want the page at all you can use the rabbithole module and link to another page Ex. Frontpage when users visit taxonomy term pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
function THEME_NAME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(&$suggestions, &$vars) {
            if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'entity.taxonomy_term.canonical' && $tid = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('taxonomy_term')) {
              $term = Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::load($tid);
              $suggestions[] = 'page__taxonomy__' . $term->getVocabularyId();
            }
          }
```

Create template file "page--taxonomy--VOCABULARYNAME.html.twig" in template folder and you can customize the page with the help of template file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, now I can alter the specific taxonomy term page :) but my issue to disable/remove node listings within the taxonomy-term.html.twig has not been resolved. I wish there were D8 module similar to this https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_term_node_listings